# Java RegExp Underscore

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace **content** (double underscores left and right, see code) in a given string, but can't get it to work. So something like this:

```
String test = "Hello! This is the content: __content__";
test.replaceAll("__content__", "Yeah!");
System.out.println("Output: " + test);
```

So the output should be: `"Output: Hello! This is the content: Yeah!"`
The regular expression in the first parameter of the replaceAll simply is wrong, but I don't know the correct one. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign return value of `replaceAll` back to original string. `replaceAll` (or any other string method) doesn't change the original string:

```
String test = "Hello! This is the content: __content__";
test = test.replaceAll("__content__", "Yeah!");
System.out.println("Output: " + test);
```

btw you don't even need a regex here, just use `replace`:

```
test = test.replace("__content__", "Yeah!");
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java strings are immutable, so `replaceAll` doesn't modify the string, but returns a new String.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
String test = "Hello! This is the content: __content__";
test = test.replaceAll("__content__", "Yeah!");
System.out.println("Output: " + test);
```

[replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) returns the resulting string!